# How to write in shell script whether a folder has a remote git repository

Tags: git, shell, terminal, osx-yosemite

I am trying to write a shell script that detects if a given folder has a remote git repository.  If so, then I will pull from the URL and push changes.  Otherwise, I just add and commit.  Here is what my code looks like:

```
# Command for add, commit, push

function save(){
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Enter a commit message!"
    echo ""
    git status
  elif [ TODO: current_directory_contains_a_remote_repository ]; then
    git add -A
    str="'$*'"
    git commit -m "$str"
  else
    git pull
    git add -A
    str="'$*'"
    git commit -m "$str"
    git push 
  fi
}
```

Finally, I'm a novice when it comes to function writing in shell script but is it also possible to reference a subfunction that does git add -A and git commit in my save() function?  I would also appreciate any feedback on good coding styles for shell scripts.

Comment: How will you handle if there's a auto-merging conflict from the `git pull`?

Comment: I am not sure, is there is a way to handle exceptions in shell script?

Comment: Shell scripts do not have exceptions. Scripts run programs, which either complete, printing results to stdout and/or stderr, and return some exit code, whose value depends on the program; or they terminate due to some sort of internal error or due to a signal. These cases also result in an exit code that is distinguishable from normal termination (some shells are better at this than others).

Answer (score 3):

Most of this is really questions about doing programming in sh or bash.  In general—and this is an opinion, which isn't really appropriate on StackOverflow—I'd recommend not even attempting to do it this way.  Still, we can answer specific questions about *Git* here, which I will rewrite a bit:

- Given that we're sure that we have a Git repository, how can we tell whether this repository has some number of *remotes?*  Which remotes does it have?
- Given that we have some branch name *B*, how do we find whether branch *B* has an *upstream* setting?

The *remotes* are simply names for some other Git repository or repositories.  Typically, a repository you made with `git clone <url>` has exactly one remote, `origin`.  To see if the remote `origin` exists we can simply ask Git for its URL, using `git config --get`:

```
url=$(git config --get remote.origin.url) || echo "there is no remote named 'origin'"
```

The exit status of `git config --get` tells us whether there was such a field.  (It's also possible to inspect the string-length of the `url` result.  This produces a slightly different answer though: if remote `origin` *does* exist, but its URL is the empty string, testing for that will claim that there is *no* remote, when the actual problem is that there *is* a remote but the empty-string URL is invalid.)

To find *all* the remotes we can have `git config` spill out all regular expression matches for the literal text `remote.` at the start of a key:

```
git config --get-regexp '^remote\.'
```

(Note that simply asking for `remote.` is wrong as `.` matches any character, and even `remote\.` is not quite right as that matches anything with `remote.` *in the middle:* these regular expressions are not anchored.  Hence `^remote\.` is the correct regular expression here.)  The output in a typical repository is:

```
$ git config --get-regexp '^remote\.'
remote.origin.url <some URL here>
remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Note that there may be zero or more `fetch` settings, and there may be additional settings for each remote.  The names of the remotes are the second field in the dot-separated keys.  To select just those fields and unique-ify them we can use `awk` or `cut` (with appropriate options) followed by `sort -u`:

```
$ git config --get-regexp '^remote\.' | cut -d. -f2 | sort -u
origin
```

(Technically `uniq` is probably sufficient, vs `sort -u`, since all the keys should be grouped together, but the Git config file format allows for duplicated section headers, and `sort -u` is generally pretty cheap here anyway.)

---

Finding the *current branch* is a matter of reading Git's current `HEAD` setting. There are several ways to do this, but the most appropriate for a script is usually to use `git symbolic-ref`, which specifically *fails* if HEAD is *not* a symbolic reference, i.e., if HEAD is *detached*.  Hence:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD) || exit
```

which sets `branch` to, e.g., `refs/heads/master`.  If HEAD is detached, `git symbolic-ref` has printed an error message, so we can just exit now (assuming that's appropriate).

We typically need to strip off `refs/heads/` at this point:

```
branch=${branch#refs/heads/}
```

Converting from "given some branch" to "the branch's upstream" is most easily done with `git rev-parse`.  This has two different ways to work its tricks:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref $branch@{upstream}
origin/master
```

or:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name $branch@{upstream}
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

which produce the outputs shown here for this case.  Note that if you use this on a branch that does not have an upstream setting, both of these produce an error message (sent to stderr) and exit nonzero:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref workbranch@{upstream}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'workbranch'
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name workbranch@{upstream}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'workbranch'
```

If we want the *current* branch's upstream, all of this is simpler, as the current branch is the default for `@{upstream}`:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{upstream}
origin/master
```

which similarly produces errors for the detached HEAD case:

```
$ git checkout --detach
HEAD is now at b7bd9486b0... Third batch for 2.19 cycle
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{upstream}
fatal: HEAD does not point to a branch
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

One should keep all of these cases in mind when writing Git scripts.